# How to configure Parquet write setting when using Flink's ParquetAvroWriters.forReflectRecord

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We're using Flink 1.14.4, and creating the Parquet file sink via:

```java
StreamingFileSink<SomePOJO> sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat(
       new Path(outputDir),
       ParquetAvroWriters.forReflectRecord(SomePOJO.class))
    .build();
```

In following the `forReflectRecord()` code, I don't see where any of the Parquet configuration values are set up, versus how `ParquetRowDataBuilder.FlinkParquetBuilder` sets up page size, etc.

Do I need to implement my own version of `ParquetAvroWriters` that does this, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up extending the `AvroParquetWriters.forSpecificRecord()` and `createAvroParquetWriter()` methods to take an additional `AvroParquetWriterConfig` parameter, which adds Optional values for the additional settings I need. The `createAvroParquetWriter()` method now looks like:

```java
    private static <T> ParquetWriter<T> createAvroParquetWriter(String schemaString,
            GenericData dataModel, AvroParquetWriterConfig parquetConfig, OutputFile out)
            throws IOException {

        final Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString);

        AvroParquetWriter.Builder<T> builder = AvroParquetWriter.<T>builder(out)
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withDataModel(dataModel);
        
        // TODO - how to configure the compression level?
        
        if (parquetConfig.getRowGroupSize().isPresent()) {
            builder.withRowGroupSize(parquetConfig.getRowGroupSize().get());
        }
        
        if (parquetConfig.getPageSize().isPresent()) {
            builder.withPageSize(parquetConfig.getPageSize().get());
        }
        
        if (parquetConfig.getCompressionCodecName().isPresent()) {
            builder.withCompressionCodec(parquetConfig.getCompressionCodecName().get());
        }
        
        if (parquetConfig.getUseDictionary().isPresent()) {
            builder.withDictionaryEncoding(parquetConfig.getUseDictionary().get());
        }
        
        return builder.build();
    }
```

I haven't found a way to control the compression level for the ZSTD codec, as the `ParquetProperties` class doesn't have support for codec-specific settings.